# Using column length to validate

Tags: doctrine-orm

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=10)
 */
protected $name;
```

What exactly is the purpose of 'length'?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

At the above URL it states: "length: Used by the 'string' type to determine its maximum length in the database. Doctrine does not validate the length of a string values for you."

I have the length defined in my database, so what is the point of adding 'length' in Doctrine? Does 'length' have *anything* to do with validation?

The only thing I can figure out is it cuts off the excess characters before trying to insert it into the database. Very annoying when I want an exception or error.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine does not apply any kind of validation on your entities: it just loads and saves data applying the required type conversions (and fails if something is wrong with your objects).

The `length` attribute is there just to aid during schema generation when you use Doctrine's schema tools.

You can still extract that value with the metadata API of Doctrine 2 ORM eventually, but consider using a proper validation library for such tasks.

Comment: What is a proper validation library?
Can I create my own validation library? If I did, where would I start(Link to a tutorial plz :D)